# Related rates, using the Pythagorean theorem or otherwise

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having a hard time understanding this question:

> A spotlight is placed on the ground, and shines on a wall 12 meters away. Frank is a 75 cm tall dog who walks at a speed of 1.6 m/s. Frank walks from the spotlight directly towards the wall, projecting a shadow onto the wall. When Frank is 9 meters from the wall
>   (a) how high is his shadow on the wall?
>   (b) how fast is the length of his shadow decreasing?

Specifically, do I relate the Pythagorean Theorem to the total distance from the spotlight to the wall, or the distance from Frank to the wall, or the distance from the spotlight to Frank? And if the latter two, how would I include the total distance into finding part (a)?

How would I set up the Pythagorean Theorem to accommodate this scenario in order to find dy/dt?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey I'm in that problem! :D Anyhow, draw a picture. That's the best thing to do in geometry problems such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagram of the situation:

```
        X
       /|
      / |
     /  |
    F   |
   /R   |
  / A   |
 /  N   |
S---K---Y
```

The Pythagorean theorem is not needed here, since we can use similar triangles. We have $SY=12$ and $FK=\frac34$; let $SK=x$. The length of Frank's shadow $y=XY$ satisfies
$$\frac{\frac34}x=\frac y{12}$$
Therefore
$$y=\frac9x$$
When Frank is 9 metres from the wall, $x=3$ and $y=\frac93=3$ metres. Continuing to the derivative:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac9{x^2}$$
We are given that
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1.6=\frac85$$
so
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{72}{5x^2}$$
When $x=3$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{72}{5\cdot3^2}=-\frac85$, i.e. the length of Frank's shadow is decreasing at 1.6 metres per second.